# Is it good practice to use Exception to prevent class from being instantiated with unwanted parameter

Tags: java, exception

I'm new to Java. I wrote a class called `QueryCondition` which is used to represent query conditions in a SQL command, such as `id > 5`, `bankBalance < 100`, etc. Obviously, a query condition like this needs to have both of the operands, so in the constructor of `QueryCondition` I check for empty or null operands and throw an exception if such is the case. Is this good practice?

```
public class QueryCondition
{
  public enum Comparator
  {
    smallerThan,
    smallerThanOrEqualTo,
    largerThan,
    largerThanOrEqualTo,
    equals,
    doesNotEqual
  }

  private final String _leftOp;
  private final String _rightOp;
  private final Comparator _comp;
  public QueryCondition( String leftOperand, Comparator compare, String rightOperand ) throws Exception
  {
    if( leftOperand == null || leftOperand.isEmpty() ||
        rightOperand == null || rightOperand.isEmpty() )
    {
      throw new Exception("QueryCondition cannot be constructed with empty operands.");
    }
    
    _leftOp = leftOperand;
    _rightOp = rightOperand;
    _comp = compare;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the exception when it is thrown. Do you plan on handling it in the place where you call the QueryCondition class? Or would it be better to handle the error in place and respond to the user from there? These are things you have to consider for yourself.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you can always set them default values in case they are null instead of throwing `Exception`. Although, in case you want to continue with an exception, I would suggest you create a personalised exception and use that one. i.e. `QueryException`

Comment: @Fullslack.dev I want to let the exception propagate upwards and let it terminate the program, since this will tell the programmer that they are doing something wrong with the way they are using QueryCondition and this should help them correct their code. Is this good practice?

Comment: IMO, this is acceptable. However, one could argue that you will be better off if you put safeguards in place upstream so that the needed parameters are not null before instantiating your query condition object. If this is tied up to your input validator, then I say OK.

Comment: If you want to let the exception propagate upwards than I can only agree with NeoChiri and Hulk to continue using the chosen path. So in a nutshell: yes it is good practice for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such precondition checks are absolutely recommended in a constructor. It is the responsibility of the constructor to establish the invariants of your class. As a constructor does not have any other way to signal failure than throwing an exception, this is the only (and correct) thing to do in most cases.

Which type of `Exception` to throw is up to you, but the currently most idiomatic way is `NullPointerException` in case of null arguments and `IllegalArgumentException` in case of other illegal values.

There is even some support built into the standard library:
[Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String)) allows you to write the null checks as

```
public QueryCondition( String leftOperand, Comparator compare, String rightOperand )
{
    _leftOp = Objects.requireNonNull(leftOperand, "left operand null");
    _rightOp = Objects.requireNonNull(rightOperand, "right operand null");
    _comp = Objects.requireNonNull(compare, "compare null");
}
```

This does not check for emptiness, though. It throws a `NullPointerException` with the message given as the second parameter if the first parameter is `null`.

Some libraries offer additional utility functions for such checks (e.g. [apache commons StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-))

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how these objects are to be constructed. Many of these protective habits are from the days of C/C++ when a bad argument could trigger a confusing memory dump. With a VM, the failure reporting is usually clearer.

In your case, I wouldn't check the string, but would assign Comparator values (which I presume is what you really want), so that the object really is created correctly. If there's to be a conversion from Strings, I usually add a static factory method that separates out all the error checking, leaving a minimal constructor.

One more thing, you don't need the leading underbars in Java. That's another habit left over from brittle languages and ascii terminals.